# How to have JHipster 6.10 produce open api 3.0. documentation instead or in addition to Swagger 2

Tags: swagger, jhipster, openapi

I have a Jhipster project as a monolith, that exposes Swagger 2 documentation at /v2/api-docs as a JSON file. The Jhipster UI also creates a Swagger 2 UI. However, I need JHipster to create an Open API 3.0 formatted JSON file but can't find any information about it. The JHipster documentation speaks about API first development with Open API 3.0 but not how to replace the produced Swagger with the new Open API standard.

Answer (score 1):

This requires upgrading to Springfox 3 and it will be available in JHipster 7 but you can have a look at how it was done to replicate in your project:

https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/12125